# Unhook $(window).resize event

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, ajax, window-resize

I create a listener for the browser window by doing the following line:

**`$(window).resize(resizeObjects);`**

My problem is at some point of the web application cycle I want to unwire this event from `window.resize`. Does anyone know how to unhook `resizeObjects` from the `window.resize` event?

Comment: This `$(window).resize(resizeObjects());` should most likely look like this: `$(window).resize(resizeObjects);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean [`.unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)?

```
$(window).unbind('resize', resizeObjects);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also try on event in jquery as follows

```
$(window).on("resize", resizeObjects);
```

later on when you want to unbind, you can do it like

```
$(window).off("resize");
```

Answer (score 0):

how about adding a variable to control the function execution?

```
var doResize = true;

$(window).resize(function() {
    if(doResize) {
        resizeObjects();
    }
});
```

and toggle doResize true or false at certain point before window resizes.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
while (variable<endvalue) {
  $(window).resize(function (){
    resizeObjects();
  });
}
```